# How can I prevent users directly accessing a SQL Server CE database and thereby bypassing business rules?

Tags: entity-framework, wcf, security, sql-server-ce

I'm working on an app that stores a local cache of information in a SQL Server CE database. I've architected my solution as a WCF service that internally uses Entity Framework 6 and a SQL Server CE backend. The WCF service enforces certain business rules. The whole thing is hosted within a Windows Service that I intend to run under the `LocalSystem` account.

Client apps on the same machine will access the WCF service which will provide limited access to the back end database. I don't want users to be able to access the database directly, thereby bypassing my business logic. Ideally, I don't want them to even be able to find it. In an ideal world I'd put the data off on a server somewhere, but my solution has to run on disconnected systems with locally cached data.

Within the bounds of reason, how can I best protect the SQL Server CE database from being accessed directly and thereby bypassing the business rules that are normally enforced by the WCF service?

Comment: [Secure it](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa237911(v=sql.80).aspx).

Comment: @RobertHarvey Securing it will be part of the solution - but simply deleting the database is another way to bypass the business rules! Hence, I'd like to hide it away and make finding it non-trivial.

Comment: Is the CE database just a cache, or is it the main data store?